# Using iterators on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, iterator

It is stated in [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) that

> In C++ pointers and arrays are closely intertwined. In particular, as
>   we’ll see, **when we use an array, the compiler ordinarily converts the
>   array to a pointer**.

I wanted to use iterators for printing an array. The program below works fine but when I try to print `arr2` or `arr3`, if I'm not mistaken, which is of type `int *`, I get an error (judging that the & operator means reference below).

> `error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    auto arr2 = arr;
    auto arr3(arr);   // I think arr2 and arr3 are of same type

    for(auto it = std::begin(arr) ; it != std::end(arr) ; ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Considering the statement, if an array is converted into a pointer by the compiler, how does this program work for printing contents of `arr` using `std::begin()` and `std::end()`  and do not work for `arr2` or `arr3` if all of them are pointers to integers?

---

**Edit**

I'm sorry if I couldn't make it clear. I hope I'll clarify the problem by this edit.

Now that I am aware that `begin()` and `end()` won't work with pointers (thanks to the answers), I wonder if the quoted text is not true as it specifies that there is an **Array -> Pointer** conversion. If what text says is true then the type of `arr` should be a pointer. Is there a problem with the quoted text at this point?

Also, is there any way that I can use `begin()` and `end()` for pointers (not STL containers) with specifying the size, possibly using the following constructor?

```
template< class T, size_t N > 
T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

Comment: As for using `begin()/end()` on pointers: You can't, **but** you can use the pointer itself as range start and pointer + size as end. Example: `std::sort(yourPointer, yourPointer + arraySize)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An array is converted to a pointer easily, but not always.  For example, if you take the address of the array or get a reference then the original array type isn't lost:

```
int a[10];
int (&ar)[10] = a; // fine
int (*ap)[10] = &a; // also fine
```

However, when you use an array in a way where most other types would be copied, the array is converted to a pointer and the pointer is copied instead.

In your example, you can use arr2 if you make it be a reference:

```
 auto &arr2 = arr;
```

Now `arr2` has type `int (&)[10]` instead of `int *`.

Comment: Thank you, that precisely answers what I actually ask. +1

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::begin` is defined for arrays but not for pointers. An array type is not the same as a pointer type.

The problem here is that apparently the `auto arr2 = arr` degrades the type from the array type to a pointer type.

Note that the problem is actually in `std::end` not in `std::begin`. After all how would `std::end` be able to give the pointer to the last+1 element when all it has is a pointer to the first element? It can't, therefore `std::end` cannot be defined for a pointer type and hence `std::begin` does not make any sense for a pointer type.

To be precise the type of `arr` is `int[10]` while that of `arr2` and `arr3` is `int*`. The former can degrade into the latter but not vice versa.

Comment: Does this mean the quoted text is not necessarily true, meaning that the compiler doesn't convert arrays into pointers?

Comment: No, the quoted text is true. The syntax `arr[b]` simply means `arr + b` where arr is decayed into a pointer to the first element and b is an integer index and normal pointer arithmetic applies. In fact looking purely at the language definition `arr[b]` is actually equal to `b[arr]` which even works! (in C at least, I'm not sure if this was maintained in C++) Anyway, any time you use an array it almost always decays immediately into a pointer, but not in every case, as indicated by the word "ordinarily" in the quoted text. A particular example would be templates like for example `std::begin`.

Comment: As for the edit to your question, basically all that `std::begin` and `std::end` do in the case of arrays is convert to a pointer. `std::begin` will simply return the array decayed to a pointer, i.e. a pointer to the first element and `std::end` will return a pointer to the last + 1 element, or `arr` + `<length>`. This is because pointers are perfectly fine iterators, they obey all the rules, (deref with *, next element with ++, prev with --.) This is no accident of course as iterators are modeled after pointers.

Comment: One final note; `std::begin` and `std::end` don't have to return pointers for array arguments, they can also return some iterator class which basically encapsulates the same pointer or some indexing variable. What they do precisely is up to the standard library implementation that you happen to have, though a good bet is that all existing implementations will return pointers as that is the simplest and most efficient implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `auto` will decay the `arr` (array type) to a pointer. And both [**`std::begin`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [**`std::end`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) can only work for containers or arrays, but not for pointers.

From C++11 standard

> **§7.1.6.4 auto specifier** [dcl.spec.auto]
>
> 1 The auto type-specifier signifies that **the type of a variable being declared shall be deduced from its initializer**
> or that a function declarator shall include a trailing-return-type.

You code cannot work here as `auto` cannot deduce array types. Just like:

```
char a[5];
auto b[5] = a;  // error, a evaluates to a pointer, which does
                // not match the array type
```

To make it work, just use C++ containers like `std::vector`:

```
vector<int> arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Comment: I get that. What I don't get is the text says "when we use an array, the **compiler ordinarily converts the array to a pointer.**" So if `arr` is converted to pointer, how does `begin()` and `end()` work? Is what the text says incorrect, meaning that arrays are not necessarily converted into pointers since `begin()` and `end()` works for containers not pointers? Also if there's any way to print `arr2` and `arr3` using iterators as in specifying the size?

Answer (score 1):

`std::begin` and `std::end` work with parameters that are C style arrays.

A possible implementation of `std::end` is:

```
template<class T, std::size_t sizeOfArray>
constexpr T *end(T (&array)[sizeOfArray])
{
  return &array[sizeOfArray];
}
```

This way `arr` is not converted in a pointer when you call `std::end(arr)` (and the information about the size of the array isn't lost... the function only accepts arrays with exactly `sizeOfArray` elements as argument).

```
template<class T>
T *end(T array[])
{
  // ?
}
```

won't work since `T array[]` behaves like a flat pointer (`T *array`), rather than a real array, when used as a function parameter.

`auto` decays the array `arr` into a pointer and the *trick* won't work anymore.